# PixiJS 6.2.0 interactive listener dont get called

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am having a problem with **PixiJS 6.2.0**.
I am generating a circle which i want to be interactive. I want to bind events on clicking, hovering etc. to it.

The circle is being shown. There is nothing above it as well. It seems like only the **pointerupoutside** event is triggering.

This is what i got so far:

```
            const buttonTexture = new PIXI.Graphics();
            buttonTexture.beginFill(0xff0000);
            buttonTexture.drawCircle(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth * 0.8);
            buttonTexture.endFill();
            buttonTexture.hitArea = new PIXI.Circle(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth * 0.8);
            buttonTexture.interactive = true;
            buttonTexture.buttonMode = true;

            buttonTexture.on('pointerdown', (e) => console.log(e));
            buttonTexture.on('pointerup', (e) => console.log(e));
            buttonTexture.on('pointerupoutside', (e) => console.log(e));
            buttonTexture.on('pointerover', (e) => console.log(e));
            buttonTexture.on('pointerout', (e) => console.log(e));
            this.pixi.app.stage.addChild(buttonTexture);
```

Clicking in the circle and clicking somewhere else after clicking in triggers a console.log.

What i tried:

- Calling everything in requestAnimationFrame
- Parsing the texture to a sprite and making the sprite interactive.
- Adding a ticker and render the stage (AFAIK This shouldn't be needed in Pixi.JS 6)

Anyone got a hint what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to tell as it seems to be working, as demonstrated here:

https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/r9AV-4uYuyDSNzM-d8mt0

Where are buttonX/buttonY being set?

Also, you don't need to specify hitArea, if it's just the same size as the graphic.

Comment: Hello, iam using a vue instance around. Can that cause issues?

Comment: Okay, while preparing a code file which represents my code without giving out too much, i noticed i had a pointer-events: none; on my parent element. I didn't know that pixi.js is relying on having pointer-events since i thought canvas is working different. Thanks tho!